# Levels of Variable and Random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest

Consider a data set **train**:

```
    z  a  
    1  1  
    0  2  
    0  1
    1  3
    0  1
    1  2
    1  1
    0  3
    0  1
    1  3
```

with a binary outcome variable **z** and a categorical predictor **a** with three levels: 1,2,3.

Now consider a data set **test**:

```
   z  a
      1
      1
      2
      1
      2
      2
      1
```

When I run the following code:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(825)
RFfit1 <- randomForest(z~a, data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)
RFprediction1 <- predict(RFfit1, test)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(RFfit1, test1) : 
  Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

I am assuming this is because the variable **a** in the **test** data set does not have three levels. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must assign it the same levels as train

```
 test$a <- factor(test$a, levels=levels(train$a))
```

Comment: That just collapses all of the levels of test back into multiple levels.

Comment: That should just change the levels of a in test to those in train. What do you mean by collapsing?

Comment: It makes the number of levels of test$a equal to the number of observations in train.

Comment: I get this error message: Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated

Comment: It makes the number of levels of test$a equal to the number of observations in test.

Comment: Yep. Had a mistake. Updated now. Sorry.